# Magento category URL with double URL

Tags: category, url, 404-page

I got a problem with my Magento shop. Today I have analysed my shop on 404-bad URL links with a online tool (brokenlinkcheck.com). I was shocked when I saw the results.

**The problem:** Every category shows up with the base-URL on the end.

[image]

So, for my knoledge I know this is wrong. I have done some research but I did not find any usefull information to take action. I hope there is a solution. How can we solve this?

Comment: Zaki, could you provide some additional information to help us look into this for you?  Please edit your original question and add this information to the bottom of your post where I added the list of items and I'll make additional updates after reviewing the data and let you know if there's anything more needed.  See my answers tub below for the info to gather.

Comment: I moved the discussion in the now-locked answer below to the Magento Chat room at http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27163496#27163496

Answer (score 0):

Zaki, could you take the following outline and gather the info I'm requesting and update your question to include it so I can work through the possible root causes of what's generating those 404 errors? I'll update the answer with the full explanation once I"Ve had a chance to review your response.

===== COPY BELOW & ADD TO QUESTION =====

Here's the information about my environment that will assist in identifying the root cause of this error:

1. Magento Edition:  EE or CE
2. Magento Version: 1.X.Y.Z or 2.X.Y.Z
3. I HAVE or HAVE NOT installed all of the available [SUPEE patches listed](https://magento.com/security/patches) as impacting the base version of Magento I have installed per the [official Magento download repository](https://www.magentocommerce.com/download)
4. This is a list of the patches that are currently installed:

   A. SUPEE-AAAA
   B. SUPEE-BBBB
   C. ....
5. I am using either:

   A. The default Magento Theme that shipped with my edition and version
    B A custom theme developed by a 3rd Party
    C. A theme I / we developed on our own
6. If A or B above WE HAVE or HAVE NOT customized the original theme files provided by Magento or th 3rd Party Vendor ***[please either put the Extension / Template file(s) relating to the Category List display on Paste Bin & add a link to them here]***
7. If you have developed your own custom theme ***[please also post the file on Paste Bin or diff the changed files and include their source in your update here]***
8. Finally, I went into our Magento Admin Back-End and viewed one of the categories that is listed in the earlier screenshot above with an incorrectly formatted URL and grabbed a screenshot of the the configuration settings of that category so you can compare it with the changes made in the template described above.  ***[Paste the screenshot here]***

===== COPY ABOVE & ADD TO QUESTION =====

Comment: Bryan, I'd suggest you place this as [a question on meta](http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). After that everyone can reference it in a comment on a question that is lacking information.

Comment: Thanks for the META suggestion!  I got halfway there and saved in Evernote as I thought it could be helpful as a general first response, especially for newcomers who aren't familiar with with either Magento SE or the standard sort of troubleshooting steps.  I'll post it up there as soon as I can.  Would you mind running through it and helping me generalize a bit in the hopes we might get the standard FAQ links included on the UI when users are posting new questions to reference it or even include it directly?

Comment: Requests for more information should be limited to the comments section. Because this request is too long it cannot / should not be converted directly to a comment. I will remove for now and you should contact the user through Chat. Meta is probably not an ideal place to carry out this conversation either but it would probably be more appropriate than here.